# Twitter Bootstrap - checkbox columns / columns within form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form field which has a number of checkboxes - how can I display the checkboxes as 3 columns instead of 1?

Something similar to this:

[image]

I've tried adding a row/span divs inside the `<div class="controls">` but it seems to be adding a left padding.

I know there is the inline checkbox example in the docs but elements aren't aligned.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can achieve such a setup by separating the checkbox blocks within the  `.control-group` container instead of each `.control` container like so:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <p class="pull-left">Payment Types</p>
    <div class="controls span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option1" id="inlineCheckbox1"> Cash
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option2" id="inlineCheckbox2"> Invoice
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> Discover
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> Financing
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option1" id="inlineCheckbox1"> Check
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option2" id="inlineCheckbox2"> American Express
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> MasterCard
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> Google Checkout
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls span2">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option1" id="inlineCheckbox1"> Traveler's Check
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option2" id="inlineCheckbox2"> Diner's Club
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> Visa
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="option3" id="inlineCheckbox3"> Paypal
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/468/show/

Comment: Andres, it seems that .form-horizontal causes the .controls to have a left padding. What do you suggest?

Comment: @RS7 you can use the `.form-vertical` class instead, which is not required per documentation. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/1/

Comment: Unfortunatwly I'm somewhat limited to using .form-horizontal - do you see any other methods?

Comment: @RS7 a dirtier approach would be to overwrite that margin-left with an id on the form like so: http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/2/, i created a `#form-custom` id and added it to the form container and then targeted the `.control` class to remove that 160px that it adds, i resetted it to the default 20px from the grid.

Comment: @AndresIlich the checkboxes in your demo http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/ do not line up in columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: @codecowboy I used the stylesheet from the bootstrap's site which has changed since this answer was written. Here is an updated fiddle with a working stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/LVFzK/468/show/

Comment: @AndresIlich thanks loads! Any idea why my first row doesn't line up - http://wordpress.lukem.co.uk/reseller-form/ ?

Comment: i tried something based off of this solution with jade and my checkboxes always line up vertically. any idea what is wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/4jnpxu03/