# horizontal row of checkboxes using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am trying to make a horizontal row of checkboxes inside a form. I have managed to get a very ugly version to work by doing:

```
div.form-group(ng-show = 'avariable')
    label 1
    input(type = 'checkbox' ng-model='weight' ng-change='weight(1)')
    label 2
    input(type='checkbox' ng-model='weight' ng-change='weight(2)')
```

I thought about writing a CSS class to put some spacing between the labels and checkboxes, but I am hoping there is a Bootstrap solution. I need it to be responsive. I have also played with .controls-row and control-group classes. They make things look nice, but the checkboxes align vertically.

EDIT: I also tried this solution based on the SO post linked from the answer below. The checkboxes still line up vertically.

```
div.control-group(ng-show = 'questionData.sweighted || questionData.eweighted')
    div.controls.span2
        label.checkbox 1
            input(type = 'checkbox' ng-model='weight' ng-change='weight(1)')
    div.controls.span2
        label.checkbox 2
            input(type = 'checkbox' ng-model='weight' ng-change='weight(2)')
    div.controls.span2
        label.checkbox 3
            input(type = 'checkbox' ng-model='weight' ng-change='weight(3)')
```

Comment: have you tried putting the checkboxes in a `<ul class="list-inline">`?

Comment: it comes out the same as my code sample above. I'm looking for a bootstrap solution that provides good spacing like the .form-group class

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before here: [Twitter Bootstrap - checkbox columns / columns within form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887893/twitter-bootstrap-checkbox-columns-columns-within-form)

"You can achieve such a setup by separating the checkbox blocks within the .control-group container instead of each .control container like so:"

See the link above for the entire explanation.

Comment: Can you put your attempt in a codepen or jsfiddle so we can have a look?

Comment: i edited my original post with the attempt. since it's jade, it doesn't look like anything in a fiddle.