# checkbox ng-repeat format in columns

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to align multiple checkboxes in columns where the checkboxes are created from a ng-repeat.

[image]
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zd0CXhbBXZfPcwt0loYU?p=preview) with example code but does not do what I want. Ideally I would like a variable to be used for the number of columns

here is a [StackOverflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887893/twitter-bootstrap-checkbox-columns-columns-within-form) example without the ng-repeat

**sample code**

```
  $scope.radii = [
    {id:.25, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:.5, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:1, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:2, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:3, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:4, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:5, name:"5 Mile"}
  ];

  // selected value is {id:2, name:"2 Mile"}
  $scope.selectedRadius = $scope.radii[3];

});
```

```
  <label class="checkbox" ng-repeat="radius in radii" id="selectradius-{{radius.id}}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="radius"
         ng-model="$parent.selectedRadius"
         ng-value="radius">

    {{radius.name}}

  </label>
```

Comment: Have you considered using Bootstrap? These are some of the layout issues it was designed to address.

Comment: Thanks to the help of Sajeetharan here is a completed sample in          [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kvCvxSvCWK8maWLAyT1F?p=preview) in case anybody is interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can align using bootstrap! Check for the index and divide the row elements,

Here is the code,

**HTML:**

```
<div   ng-controller="GrokController"   class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="radius in radii" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox"  
               ng-model="radii[$index].name">&nbsp;<span>{{radii[$index  ].id}}</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox"  
               ng-model="radii[$index].name">&nbsp;<span>{{radii[$index  ].id}}</span></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="checkbox"  
               ng-model="radii[$index].name">&nbsp;<span>{{radii[$index  ].id}}</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('GrokController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.radii = [
    {id:.25, name:"1/4 Mile"},
    {id:.5, name:"1/2 Mile"},
    {id:1, name:"1 Mile"},
    {id:2, name:"2 Mile"},
    {id:3, name:"3 Mile"},
    {id:4, name:"4 Mile"},
    {id:5, name:"5 Mile"}
  ];

}]);
```

Working [`App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/vm3j4akp/414/)

Comment: To get unique values in each column you need to update the index e.g. `[$index + 1]`