# displaying checkboxes in multiple cols in Angular 6 reactive form

Tags: angular, checkbox, multiple-columns, dynamic-controls

[Bootstrap to display dynamic checkboxes in 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559332/bootstrap-to-display-dynamic-checkboxes-in-3-columns)

I am following this example to create a list of dynamic checkboxes across 3 columns, currently trying to make it work using static data but later will get from service. I am not sure what is incorrect.
here is how they are being displayed. How to get data instead of Object
[image]
Template:

```
<div class="col-xs-4" formArrayName='options'
     *ngFor="let option of ReportsForm.controls.options.controls; let i = index">
    <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" /> {{options[i].option}}
</div>
<button>submit</button>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { asEnumerable } from 'linq-es2015';
import { ReportingService } from '../../services/reporting.service';
import { NotificationsService } from 'angular2-notifications';
import { ExcelService } from '../../services/excel.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-dyn',
  templateUrl: './report-dyn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-dyn.component.scss']
})
export class ReportDynComponent implements OnInit {
    ReportsForm: FormGroup;

    options = [
        { id: 1, option: 'chk 1' },
        { id: 2, option: 'chk 2' },
        { id: 3, option: 'chk 3' },
        { id: 4, option: 'chk 4' },
        { id: 5, option: 'chk 5' },
        { id: 6, option: 'chk 6' },
        { id: 7, option: 'chk 7' },
        { id: 8, option: 'chk 8' },
        { id: 9, option: 'chk 9' },
        { id: 10, option: 'chk 10' },
        { id: 11, option: 'chk 11' },
        { id: 12, option: 'chk 12' },
        { id: 13, option: 'chk 13' },
        { id: 14, option: 'chk 14' },
        { id: 15, option: 'chk 15' },
        { id: 16, option: 'chk 16' },
        { id: 17, option: 'chk 17' },
        { id: 18, option: 'chk 18' }
    ]; 
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        ////trying 3 col approach
        const controls = this.options.map(c => new FormControl(true));

        this.ReportsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            options: new FormArray(controls)
        });

        var groups = asEnumerable(this.options)
            .Select((option, id) => { return { option, id }; })
            .GroupBy(
            x => Math.floor(x.id / 3),
                x => x.option.option,
                (key, options) => asEnumerable(options).ToArray()
            )
            .ToArray();
    }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your formControls in class file?

Comment: You've asked this question twice with slightly different titles. You need to delete one of the questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394631/angular-6-reactive-form-how-to-add-dynamic-checkboxe-to-3-columns

Comment: @Stephen, done! While trying to solve found this approach, but didn't work, and hence 2 posts

Comment: @Chellappan, Modified the code to add formControl but still not working. Please guide

Comment: formarray is based on index so you need to pass index of ngfor.  modify your html like this <div class="col-xs-4" formArrayName=''options' *ngFor="let option of ReportsForm.get('options').controls; let i = index">
                        <input id="{{option}}" [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" [checked]=false /> {{option}}
                    </div>

Comment: @Chellappan, I am getting closer. displaying 3 cols checkboxes, but now displaying [object Object]. I have modified the code. Please guide.thx

Comment: Try {{options[i].option}}

Comment: already tried that first

Comment: still are you getting same output?

Comment: yes, doesn't make difference. I am thinking it might have to do with linq/Enumerable part

Comment: if it possible can you create stackblitz?

Comment: worked! modified template to:     <div class="col-xs-4" formArrayName='options'
         *ngFor="let option of ReportsForm.controls.options.controls; let i = index">
        <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox" /> {{options[i].option}}
    </div>